# Convert flat, associative array into 2d associative array without foreach() or passing by reference

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, iteration

I want to know what other options there are beyond using a `foreach(` loop to create the associative 2d output array that I want.

Input array is:

```
$arr = array(
    '4X2' => 86,
    '4X3' => 9,
    '4X4' => 5,
    '6X2' => 14,
    '6X4' => 1
);
```

Output array that I want to achieve is:

```
Array
(
    [4X2] => Array
        (
            [title] => 4X2
            [search] => &vconfiguration[]=4X2
            [count] => 86
        )

    [4X3] => Array
        (
            [title] => 4X3
            [search] => &vconfiguration[]=4X2
            [count] => 9
        )

    [4X4] => Array
        (
            [title] => 4X4
            [search] => &vconfiguration[]=4X4
            [count] => 5
        )

    [6X2] => Array
        (
            [title] => 6X2
            [search] => &vconfiguration[]=6X2
            [count] => 14
        )

    [6X4] => Array
        (
            [title] => 6X4
            [search] => &vconfiguration[]=6X4
            [count] => 1
        )    
)
```

I've used `array_walk()` to achieve the output, but in it I'm using the array passed by reference which I don't want to do. This is my solution to do this but I want to avoid passing the result array by reference (&$result).

```
$result = array();
array_walk($filterFacet, function($v, $k) use (&$result) {
  $result[$k] = array(  
      'title' => $k,  
      'search' => '&vconfiguration[]=' . $k,  
      'count' => $v  
      );
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "pass by reference"? Do you have a real reason to do so, or is it just a personal dislike? An alternative would be array_map, which works similarly, but you have to return each element

Comment: @MarkBaker i just wanted to know if there are other ways of doing this

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329), but here goes...

To directly return the populated associative 2d array, iterate the keys of the input array with `array_reduce()` and use those keys to access the globally-scoped original values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SdpX6))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($arr),
        fn($result, $k) => $result
            + [
                $k => [
                    'title' => $k,
                    'search' => "&vconfiguration[]=$k",
                    'count' => $arr[$k]
                ]
            ],
        []
    )
);
```

---

To modify the original values by reference, use `array_walk()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RbL4M)

```
array_walk(
    $arr,
    fn(&$v, $k) =>
        $v = [
            'title' => $k,
            'search' => "&vconfiguration[]=$k",
            'count' => $v
        ]
);
var_export($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

See **[Live Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/3211a)**

You can achieve this without using pass by reference by using a combination of `array_map` and `array_keys`

**Method 1**

```
$arr = array(
    '4X2' => 86,
    '4X3' => 9,
    '4X4' => 5,
    '6X2' => 14,
    '6X4' => 1
);

$result = array_map(function ($key, $count) {
    $title = strtolower(str_replace('X', 'x', $key));
    $search = '&vconfiguration[]=' . $key;
    
    return [
        'title' => $key,
        'search' => $search,
        'count' => $count
    ];
}, array_keys($arr), $arr);

$result = array_combine(array_keys($arr), $result);
// Print the output array
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

**Method 2:**

you can achieve the desired output by iterating through the input array and creating a new array with the specified structure.

```
$arr = array(
    '4X2' => 86,
    '4X3' => 9,
    '4X4' => 5,
    '6X2' => 14,
    '6X4' => 1
);

$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $count) {
    // Convert the key to lowercase and replace 'X' with 'x'
    $title = strtolower(str_replace('X', 'x', $key));
    
    // Build the search string
    $search = '&vconfiguration[]=' . $key;

    // Create the output array for the current key
    $result[$title] = array(
        'title' => $key,
        'search' => $search,
        'count' => $count
    );
}

// Print the output array
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The asker requires a non-foreach solution and your first snippet does not preserve the first level keys.

Comment: $result = array_combine(array_keys($arr), $result);  add code before print result for preserve the first level keys method 1 -  please check @mickmackusa  can you please update the useful answer to public.

Comment: Your first snippet lacks directness/elegance because after looping with `array_map()`, another loop is executed via `array_combine()`. Clearly `array_map()` is not a wise choice for this task.